# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}((2a-b)+\frac{b-a}{2}2^n),a,b\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$2a-b$ is a constant so the limit is
$$(2a-b)+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{b-a}{2}2^n)$$

If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{b-a}{2}2^n)=\infty$

is the limit of

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}((2a-b)+\frac{b-a}{2}2^n)=\infty$$?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: not quite. What happens if $a=b$?

Comment: @Chilango Then is $a$ or $b$

Comment: If $a=b$ then the limit is $2a-b=a$ because in this case you have a constant sequence.